# Page displaying how BibTeX entries are presented to the user

Tags: bibtex

Can anyone provide a page which demonstrates how BibTeX entries are presented to the user?

I found [this page](http://nwalsh.com/tex/texhelp/bibtx-7.html) which has an explanation about each entry, but I need a website showing how a style (I prefer the default style used by LaTeX) interprets those BibTeX elements and how they are presented to the user.

Let's take for example `article`

> Required fields: author, title, journal, year

and

> Optional fields: volume, number, pages, month, note, key

Is there a webpage to demonstrate how an article will be presented if all fields are available?

Comment: You can use the examples from the bibliographical database that comes with `biblatex`: [biblatex-examples.bib](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/biblatex-examples.bib).

Comment: Answers to your question will critically depend on which bibliography style is in use. E.g., will full first and middle names be shown, or only initials? Will the names be set in plain text font or in smallcaps? Will the titles of journal articles be typeset "plain" or enclosed in quotation marks (and which types of quotation marks)? Will the journal's name be set in italics or plain? Will the year be shown right after the authors' names or at the end? These are all formatting decisions that are handled by the style file in use.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [BibTeX Style Examples](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html). Quoting from the introduction:

> It can be difficult to decide which of the large range of BibTeX style
>   files is closest to the format needed. The following provides examples
>   using a variety of public-domain `.bst` files that can be [downloaded]
>   from CTAN (Comprehensive TeX Archive Network). [...]
>
> Some of the BibTeX styles below require auxiliary LaTeX styles, so
>   their representation here is only approximate. In each case, citations
>   are given as they would appear in the body of a document. These are
>   followed by their appearance in the reference list.